# Ajax with jquery validation unobstrusive and Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, unobtrusive-validation

fellas! I am trying to use ajax with jquery validation unobstrusive.

At the first page load (before the ajax call), the validation works fine (required text, StringLength   and RegularExpression). But, after the call is fired and the ModelState is not validated (server side), a Partial View is returned.

The problem is that, after the Partial View return, the validation stops working. I mean, the required text is visible but stuck (and StringLength and RegularExpression doesn't work any more). Besides that, the button looks like 'desabled' and I can not call the ajax method again. And, the scroll bar disappears.

Tks in advance, guys.

My sacCheckout.js:

```
$(function () {

$("#Mybtn").click('show.bs.modal', function () {
    var options = {};
    options.type = "POST";
    options.url = "/api/CheckOut";
    options.dataType = "JSON";
    options.cache = true;
    options.async = true;
    contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    options.data = {
        "IdPed": $("#IdPed").val(),
        "CodCar": $("#CodCar").val(),
        "IsC": $("#IsC")[0].checked
    };

    options.beforeSend = function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
       
        // Show my modal spin loading
        $('#itemLoader').modal('toggle');
        $('#itemLoader').modal('show');
    };
   
    options.success = function (data) {
        if (data.success)
        {
            // ok, success
            if (data.idPed != null) {
                window.location.href = "/app/ped/ped?Id=" + data.idPed;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // 'error', redirect to complete a value
            if (data.msg == "0") {
                window.location.href = "/identity/account/edituser";
            }

            // 'error' show on the same modal
            if (data.msg == "1") {
                var modal = $("#itemLoader");
                modal.find('.modal-body .spinner-border').hide();
                modal.find('.modal-body .far').show();
                modal.find('.modal-body #ModalStatus').text("");
                modal.find('.modal-body #ModalMsg').text("Error call 0800 3232");
            }
        }
    };

    options.error = function (res) {
        // Hide modal spin loading
        $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
        $('#itemLoader').modal('dispose');

        // modelstate was not valid, so get the Partial View return to show unobstrusive required text...
        $('#chkForm').html(res.responseText);
    };
    $.ajax(options);
});
});
```

My View Model SacCheckOutViewModel.cs:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} must not be empty.")]
[StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Must be between {2} and {1} characters.")]
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Must have only numbers.")]
public string CodCar { get; set; }
```

My controller:

```
 [HttpPost("/api/CheckOut")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> CheckOut([Bind("IdPed, IsC, CodCar")] SacCheckOutViewModel checkOut)
 {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

        List<SacViewModel> sac = JsonSerializeSessionHelper.Get<List<SacViewModel>>(HttpContext.Session, "sac");

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _IAppSac.ShowSac(user, sac);

            return PartialView("_SacPartialView", result);
        }

        // Se IsC checked
        if (checkOut.IsC )
        {
            if (user.IsC == null)
            {
                TempData["del"] = "Add your value Isc";
                return Json(new { success = false, msg = "0" });
            }
        }
         
        int idPed = await _IAppSac.AddPed(user.Id, checkOut, sac, HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(), Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString());
        if (idPed == 0)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, msg = "1" });
        }
       
        return Json(new { success = true, idPed });
   }
```

My main index.cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div id="chkForm">
            <form>
                <partial name="_SacPartialView" model="Model" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
     <script src="~/js/sacCheckout.js"></script>
}
```

My partial view _SacPartialView.cshtml

```
<div class="card bg-light mt-2">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="text-info float-left">Pack</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body m-1 p-1">
        <span class="d-block input-group-sm">
           <label class="control-label">Code:</label>
           <input asp-for="CodCar" type="text" class="form-control small col-4" />
           <span asp-validation-for="CodCar" class="text-danger"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-12 text-secondary small">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-2">
                <input asp-for="@Model.IsC" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="IsC">Is Isc?</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-block my-2 mb-3">
    <a asp-area="App" asp-controller="Produto" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
    </a>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pulse" id="Mybtn" value="Send" /> @*data-toggle="modal" data-target="#itemLoader" />*@
</div>

<input asp-for="IdPed" value="@Model.IdPed" type="hidden" /> ...
```

I am using a shared _Layout.cshtml with my scripts:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <!-- Validation -->
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <!-- Globalize -->
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-globalize/1.4.2/content/Scripts/globalize.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery.validation.globalize/1.1.0/content/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

</environment>
```

Comment: I don't see how you render your partial view.  In your ajax should be something like -   options.success= function (result) {   $("#chkForm").html(result);} Where is it?

Comment: In the options.error function. This function is fired ok when my modelstate is not valid.

Comment: What are you going to validate ? Nobody validates error

Comment: Going to validate my required field. I got you... but when I try validate my model state, and it is not valid, options.error function is getting fired.

Answer (score 2):

I am using for javascript form validation this code:

```
         $(divId).html(result); // divId partial view div tag id 
                                  //  in your case "chkForm"
        var newForm = $(formId); /formId you have to assign to form in your case 

        newForm.removeData("validator");    // Added by jQuery Validate
        newForm.removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");   // Added by jQuery 
                                                        //  Unobtrusive Validation
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(newForm);
```

Comment: After searching so much, your solution was the only one that worked for me. Thank you!